# Alternative to enabling data connection

Tags: android, data-connections

On android 2.3 the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />` is not allowed anymore for non-system applications. Is there an alternative to enable/disable data connection, besides that one where you modify APN name? I found `Data Enabler Widget` on Android Market that does that, but I can't seem to understand how. Can anyone help me?

Thanks! - Alex Ady

Comment: I am also dying to know how this `Data Enabler Widget` manages to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, so I'm closing this question. The alternative is to simply display the mobile settings activity if a level 10 API or higher is detected, or continue with direct enable from code otherwise. I keep the `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`, but only use it the API is under level 10.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change data connection (3g, 2g, etc), but you can enable/disable wifi connection through this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to work with wi-fi, but data connection is the problem here.